# Migrating changes from Patch Organization questions

Tags: managed-package, patch

Is there any native way to migrate change from a Patch Organization to the Development (main dev) Organization? Seems to me the only way to do it is with GIT or some other version control system. (or deployment of code from patch to dev from MM of Force.com IDE (which I refuse to use)).

Just need confirmation that this is the case or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you are right, that is a manual process that you could help using stash, or git with force.com ide, eclipse sublime... but at the end is extracting the changes from the patch org to and once you have them, merge them into the main org where the package is.

(unless you are in a sanbox to update the code to your production org. But then we won't be speaking about "Patch" org, that is created from a specific version in your main org that contains the package :) )

Hope it helps, and sorry for the news.

Thanks,
Carolina.